# Which network topology does Windows 'hostednetwork' use? Is it equivalent to Ad-Hoc's topology?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I set up a AP using the following command:
`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=DotA key=pass keyUsage=persistent`

I am eager to know what topology (star, mesh etc.) does it use, so I may use it optimally as per my needs.

Comment: Only guessing, but "hosted" is likely to mean AP (managed) mode.

Comment: @grawity: Your saying that the admin _manages_ the topology? If I create the network with above stated command, what shall be the topology its following?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the computer becomes an AP, and "managed" is another name for WiFi networks based around an AP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MSDN article [About the Wireless Hosted Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243(v=vs.85).aspx), "Hosted Network" creates a WiFi network where the computer acts as an AP ("SoftAP" in that article). The topology is therefore the same as in all managed WiFi networks (ones that use an AP) – a **star** with the hosting computer (the AP) in its center.

Comment: Like other APs it will use **star** and `ad-hoc` uses **mesh** if am not mistaken?